# errors when trying to connect html to geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

new user here

I'm trying to connect my geth client to a HTML page using web3 such that the webpage can interact with my local testnet.

I have tried several approaches but I always end up with errors:

When I use web3 v1.0 I use the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="web3.js-1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8082');
```

I get the following error:
ReferenceError: require is not defined

When I use web3 v 0.20 I use:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="web3.js-develop/lib/web3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8082');
var version = web3.version.api;
console.log(version);
if(!web3.isConnected()) {
    console.log("not connected");
} else {
  console.log("connected");
}
```

I get:
this.currentProvider.isConnected is not a function

I also tried to use the IRC instead of http:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="web3.js-develop/lib/web3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Web3 = require('web3');
var net = require('net');
var web3 = new Web3('path_to_geth/geth.ipc', net);
```

I get:
Error: Cannot find module 'net'

Sorry if this is an obvious mistake on my side but I can't seem to figure it out. Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`require()` is not a part of standard JavaScript. It is a special function for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) which allows programs to import modules.

When using Web3.js on a basic HTML/JS page, only need to import the library using the `<script>` tag, which it seems you are already doing.

In terms of connecting to geth, I recommend you follow this code template provided by the [MetaMask developer FAQ](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
  startApp()

})
```

Here you can update your `HttpProvider` settings to match your localhost port, which will always be used as a fallback.

Additionally, you can use MetaMask to connect to your geth instance, in which case the page will use the `web3.currentProvider` provided by MetaMask.

Comment: when I try your code, the output is: "No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!" followed by "ReferenceError: startApp is not defined" and if I try to check for connection: "ReferenceError: web3 is not defined". Do I need to import something else besides web3?

Comment: So the first message is fine. It is saying that you dont have metamask, and instead will use your HTTP provider. The `startApp()` function call is just sudo code to start running your other functions. You can't just blindly copy this code, modify it for your needs.